# How can I connect multiple monitors to a single PC by LAN cables?

Tags: display

I saw somewhere that several LCDs were connected to a single PC - not by video cards but by using LAN cables and a device like a modem or router. The LCDs were used to display different videos from the PC. I checked the LCDs but I didn't find any network ports on them; there was another device next to each LCD that connected them to the PC.

Does anyone knows what this might be and how to create one?

If so, how can I access these monitors in my C# application?

Answer (score 5):

This requires special hardware, such as a VGA or HDMI Cat extender.

[image]

> The Extender system is made up of local transmitter and remote receiver units that are connected together by CAT5/5e twisted pair cable (not included, we recommend you use our bulk cable or UTP CAT5e Solid Core cable). The remote receiver unit connects to your distant monitor or projector, the local transmitter unit connects to the computer system's video port. In addition, the VGA signal is duplicated allowing a local monitor to be connected for convenient user operation.

- (for VGA) http://www.lindy.co.uk/vga-extender-cat5-5e-300m/32537.html
- (for HDMI) http://www.lindy.co.uk/hdmi-cat5e-6-extender-35m/38001.html

Comment: Heh, pretty cool idea.

Comment: thank you , after we connect LCDs to the PC how can i access these monitors in my application . when we use HDMI cables , i can access them by using "Screen" class .

Comment: @royasaz - I have no experience with the product but I'd be **very** surprised if they where treated any differently than normal screens. So you should be able to use the Screen class as normal.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dedicated cable and only short distance, a passive adapter might be enough, given your cable is of high enough quality: http://www.hdtvsupply.com/at-dvi15srs.html

[image: passive dvi-cat5 adapter]

Comment: This is indeed a possibility if the run is only a few meters.